# Meaning of $\dashv\vdash$

Tags: logic, analytic-geometry, formal-proofs

I was looking at [ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Main_Page)'s articles 'Definition:Equidistance' and 'Definition:Between (Geometry)'and came across the symbol '$\dashv\vdash$.'  What does it mean?

Comment: Basically "can prove and be proved by"; or "is syntactically equivalent with" (for a given formal system).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\dashv\vdash$, means that two statements are [interderivable](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Interderivable).   It's an expression of **logical equivalence**, or *syntactic equivalence*, in formal proofs.

$$p\dashv\vdash q\qquad\text{ means that }\quad p\vdash q\quad\text{ and }\quad q\vdash p$$

.

---

PS: The turnstyle, $\vdash$, is the logical implication symbol in formal proofs; which may be read aloud as "therefore".

Comment: I thought that '$A \vdash B$' meant 'if A, then B' and that '$\therefore$' meant 'therefore.

Comment: You can use "If $A$, then $B$", "Because $A$, therefore $B$", "From $A$, follows $B$", "$A$ proves $B$", or however you want to announce it.  The tri-dot "therefore" held the same sense, but it is not often used as such any more, except to punctuate the end of a proof.

Comment: Ah, I see.  That makes sense, and I'd up-vote your comment if I had enough reputation on this Stack Exchange site.

Comment: @RandomDSdevel: Note that there are 3 distinct notions, "$A \vDash B$" (any interpretation that satisfies $A$ also satisfies $B$) and "$A \vdash B$" (from $A$ we can derive $B$) and "$A \Rightarrow B$" / "$A \rightarrow B$" (if $A$ then $B$). So technically what you said is not correct. In many formal systems, the 3 notions are in some sense equivalent, such as for first-order logic, where the first two because of the completeness theorem and the last two because of the deduction theorem.